# MSVC Unicode not displaying English

Tags: c++, unicode, asianfonts

My problem is that my Unicode C++ program that I'm writing in MSVC express is displaying all strings in an Asian font. What might cause this and how can I display the strings in English?

Comment: What operating system version? What locale are you in when you run it?

Comment: More info: Windows Vista, MSVC Expres 2008. Its a DirectX project.

I've done research and found that using the L"some text" string literal conversion my text is displayed in English. However when I convert a variable (for example (LPCWSTR)myString), it compiles yet displays in specifically Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. When casting anything other than a WCHAR* the compiler interprets it in an undesired way(displaying Japanese fonts rather than English). Initializing the used strings as WCHAR* not only is accepted by the compiler but gives the desired result of English fonts.

I don't know how well this will apply to anyone else's problems but it has solved mine. Thanks to bmargulies and AraK for responding(I was away when you did I appologize).

Comment: Such casts are wyas to tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing", not "guess what I wanted". If you need a `WCHAR*`, provide the string as a `WCHAR[]`, not as an `int`, `float` or `char[]`.